# Firebase Storage OnFailure Not Working with await. why?

Tags: android, kotlin, error-handling, task, firebase-storage

I use firebase storage to download file like below.
on succsess is working and downloads the data. But when there is an error, onFailurelistener not working. For example if i write the file path incorrect nothing happens and my app freezes. How to make onfailure works.

```
suspend fun readFireBaseFile(context: Context): String {
    var data: String = "will come from firebase"

   
        val maxBytes = 3 * 1024 * 1024L 

        Firebase.initialize(context)
        val ref = Firebase.storage.reference.child("/files/myFile.json")
        
        val mytask = ref.getBytes(maxBytes)
        
        mytask.addOnFailureListener() {
            
            println("ERROR")    // not working !!!!!!!!!!!!!!
        }
        
        mytask.addOnSuccessListener {
            println("SUCCSESS")  // Working
        }
        val byteData = mytask.await()
        data = String(byteData)
    
    return data
}
```

i Want to handle errors, exeptions ...

Comment: If your code freezes, you should do some debugging to figure out which line of code is causing that, and update your question to explain more specifically what isn't working the way you expect.

Answer (score 0):

When using `await()` you no longer need to manually add those listeners because the function will throw the exception for you to `catch`. So your code would be:

```kotlin
suspend fun readFireBaseFile(context: Context): String {
    var data: String = "will come from firebase"

   
        val maxBytes = 3 * 1024 * 1024L 

        Firebase.initialize(context)
        val ref = Firebase.storage.reference.child("/files/myFile.json")
        
        val mytask = ref.getBytes(maxBytes)
        
        try {
            val byteData = mytask.await()            
            println("SUCCSESS")
            data = String(byteData)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            println("ERROR")
        }
    
    return data
}
```